# What is the best way to test if a CPLString is not empty?

Tags: gdal

If I define a CPLString this way:

```
CPLString osString;
```

And I want to check if osString is not empty, what would be the best way?

My bet:

```
if (osString.c_str() == NULL)
```

But I find it a little rusty... Is there any other better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gdal CPLString is a convenient class for std::string

```
class CPL_DLL CPLString : public gdal_std_string
{
...
};
```

and gdal_std_string is a typedef for std::string or MSVC string class

```
00213 # define gdal_std_string string
00214 #else
00215 # define gdal_std_string std::string
00216 #endif
```

Source:[GDAL API docs](http://www.gdal.org/cpl__string_8h_source.html)

so basically CPLString can be checked for emptiness using `std::string::empty()`

in your case:

`osString.empty()` returns `True` if its empty.